# Do I have to wait 60 days to transfer website from hosting service to another hosting?

Tags: website, dns, web-hosting, plesk

My current website is hosted on a website called [my hosting panel](https://district9.my-hosting-panel.com:8443/login.php3).

It has Plesk installed over there, and it's really frustrating trying to upload files, see the changes, since you put www.yoursite.com takes you to plesk main website, and http://yoursite.com takes you to your uploaded site files.

FTP passwords didn't work. Sometimes, using www.yoursite.com takes you again to the damn plesk "welcome" page.

One week has passed, and support team couldn't fix it.

I would like to know if it's possible to change my hosting, and publish my files on another hosting company. Or do I have to wait 60 days to make this change on DNS?

thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I *believe* the "60-day hold" rules you are thinking about refers to ICANN's policy on transferring **domain names** between registrars. ***Not*** to changing your DNS settings which would allow you to move your website to another host.

[Policy on Transfer of Registrations between Registrars](http://www.icann.org/en/transfers/policy-12jul04.htm)

So, unless you have some sort of minimum service-length contract with the web host, you should be able to move between them freely.